# AWS RDS MS SQL Unable to connect

Tags: sql-server, node.js, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to my newly created ms sql database. However, I am getting an error when I try to connect. Error : Unable to connect to the database: { SequelizeConnectionError: Failed to connect to ....

```
const sequelize =new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'mssql',
    dialectModulePath: 'tedious',
    dialectOptions: {
 driver: '**SQL Server Native Client 11.0  - is this correct?**',
      instanceName: '**where do i get this?**'
    },
    host: '**what do i put for this?'is this the end point?**',
    port: '1433',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password,
    database: '**what do i put for this?**',
    pool: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        idle: 10000
      }
  });
```

Comment: I don't know much about sequelize, but you can find the instanceName  doing a `SELECT @@servername`, the host is the endpoint, the database is the name of your database that you want to connect to (a SQL Server instance serves an X amount of databases, each one has it's own files). If you use SSMS, the databases are the ones listed below (guess what) "Databases".

Answer (score 0):

dbname is the name of the database you're interacting with (you entered this into aws)

also make sure you did `npm install tedious -S`

```
const sequelize =new Sequelize('dbname', 'dbusername', 'dbpassword', {
    host: 'http://endpoint-from-aws.com'
    dialect: 'mssql',
    operatorsAliases: false,
    pool: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        idle: 10000
    }
});
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started.html

Comment: Thanks. if I leave 'dbname' empty, I am able to connect. However when I add a value, i get an error

Comment: There should be a dbname. Otherwise you have to specify the dbname on every call

Answer (score 0):

```
const sequelize = await new Sequelize(database, user, password, { host: 'rds-end-point', dialect: 'mysql' });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 